# Using Cakephp 1.3 CLI on Hostgator

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, command-line-interface, host

I'm using Hostgator.com and I'm trying to bake apps via ssh console. I have connected successfully to via SSH. I have the cakephp folder located at http://www.domainname.com/cakephp

the initial cakephp installation is working fine. Connected to database etc.

This is a list of paths from Hostgator: [List](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/linux-application-paths-what-is-the-path-to)

here is my .bash_profile:
    # .bash_profile

```
# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
     . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

export PS1="$ "

alias www="cd /home/username/public_html"

export PATH="/usr/bin/php/bin:/home/username/public_html/cakephp/cake/console:$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

When i open terminal I do this: www [enter] -> cake bake [enter]

then I get this problem: -jailshell: /home/username/public_html/cakephp/cake/console/cake: Permission denied

if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated. If I have forgot to mention something please tell me asap so I can tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the executable flag on the cake script.

```
www
chmod +x cakephp/cake/console/cake
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks sir =) lifesaver. Hopefully This will help someone on hostgator.com servers.